# Month dropdown in jQuery datepicker GUI does not agree with values GUI sets

Tags: jquery, date

First initialize all date pickers:

```
$(".datepicker").datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        dateFormat: 'MM d, yy',
        onSelect: function(dateText) {
            $('#recurrence-start-time-container').show().animate({backgroundColor:'#FF0'}, 400).animate({backgroundColor:'#FFF'}, 500);
        }
    });
```

Then add an onSelect to the repeat_start element:

```
$(".datepicker[name='repeat_start']").datepicker( 'option' , 'onSelect', function(dateStr) {
            var min = $(this).datepicker('getDate') || new Date(); // Selected date or today if none
            console.log('Min:'+min);
            var max = new Date(min.getTime());
            max.setMonth(max.getMonth() + 1); // Add one month
            console.log('Max:'+max);
            $(".datepicker[name='repeat_end']").datepicker('option', {minDate: min, maxDate: max});
        } );
```

So for example `repeat_start` is initialized with a value of April 28, 2016 and `repeat_end` is initialized with no set value.  I change `repeat_start` to April 29 and click in `repeat_end`.  The console gets

```
Min:Fri Apr 29 2016 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)  
Max:Sun May 29 2016 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)
```

But the GUI shows the wrong month:

[image: screenshot of gui]

However if I select the 29th visible there I get a set value of "April 29, 2016".  If I use the triangle button to change months the drop down in GUI steps up to february BUT clicking at the max date on that 29th gets "May 29, 2016" as set value.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce this, man: https://jsfiddle.net/nu0pL4c3/

Comment: @JosephMarikle in imitation of your code I removed `changeMonth: true` from my initialization and the issue disappeared